# What's the difference between an In-memory database and relational database + NoSQL Database?

Tags: database, nosql, relational, in-memory

it seems that databases can be divided into relational dBs also called SQL databases and NoSQL databases. My question is where do in-memory-databases fit into this picture? I only find in-memory-databases use the main memory as data storage instead of the disk storage. Can both relational and NoSQL Databases use this in-memory-technology ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL/NoSQL refers to the DB *type* while in-memory relates to where the data is physically stored. The two are orthogonal (unrelated), meaning, any DB regardless if it's SQL/NoSQL can be ran both in-memory or on disk.